# Core Data losing entities

Tags: debugging, ios5, core-data

I can't understand what is happening here...

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:kTransaction inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:kDate ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    NSPredicate *pred;

    if (self.willShowDebts) {
        pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isDebt = YES"];  
    }else {
        pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isLoan = YES"];
    }
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    [self setFetchController:nil];
    self.fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"fetch objects  %i",[[self.fetchController fetchedObjects] count]);

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I do this about 4 time in my app ... And here it doesn't quite work ... the first time it shows all entities, but if I go back (it's in a navigation controller) and then go to this view again everything is gone ... What gives

```
2012-09-06 13:54:15.994 app[1126:fe03] fetch objects  3
2012-09-06 13:54:19.254 app[1126:fe03] fetch objects  0
2012-09-06 13:54:22.145 app[1126:fe03] fetch objects  0
2012-09-06 13:54:24.328 app[1126:fe03] fetch objects  0
```

This is the log output...
Any ideas??

Comment: The only obvious things that you use to create results are `self.context` and `self.willShowDebts` (assuming you're not explicitly deleting anything).  It would be interesting to log both of those to see if they change between calls.

Comment: The self.context is set up in the ViewDidLoad method ... it is not nil. The self.willShowDebt is an assigned BOOL property ... I don't think it's set up wrong but will double check

Comment: self.willShowDebts was not set up right ......

Answer (score 0):

Is your managed object context correctly set up each time (or is it `nil`)?

Put a breakpoint on the first line of your method and step through, checking that everything is as you expect.

Comment: It is definitely not nil ... :(